# Real time data sync between azure cosmos db( with mongo api) and elastic search

Tags: java, azure, elasticsearch, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, monstache

In our stack there is both Azure Cosmos DB(with Mongo Api) as well as Elastic search with similar indices. The cosmos DB gets updated frequently with some apis running in the backend. This update also needs to get reflected in elastic search which is being queried by other applications, so the data in elastic search and Cosmos DB should be in sync.

I am trying to see if there are any tools which can cater to this requirement to sync my Azure Cosmos DB with elastic search in real time. I have tried with a third party tool like monstache but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work due to the below mentioned issue -
[Error starting change stream](https://github.com/rwynn/monstache/issues/624#issuecomment-1187002331).

Comment: Maybe something like change feed could work for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-design-patterns ?